# Tensorflow.js Face Landmark Detection: "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined, js engine: hermes"

Tags: expo, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

So I'm trying to import the following library ([@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection)) to my expo managed application.

as per the documentation in their Github README, I installed the dependencies via npm, and followed the import instructions:

```
import * as faceLandmarksDetection from '@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
import '@mediapipe/face_mesh';
```

But simply including the import statement, specifically importing @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection, gives me the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined, js engine: hermes"

The source for the error is face_mesh.js, where the error lies in the code `navigator.userAgent.includes("Mac")`.

Is it not possible to use this tensorflow.js model with the Expo CLI?

Tried changing backend to RN-webgl, etc.

Comment: Facing same issue with react native.

Comment: There are a few things you could try
* use tfjs-react-native
* If using expo, try   
"expo": {
    "jsEngine": "jsc"
  }
* If its a bare app, which was in my case - you can go to the andorid module -> gradle.properties and set hermesEnabled to false (something similar should be there for ios), defaults to js engine.
* Here are a few links that might help to debug more errors -> https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/7937